# error translating a simple program to c++

Tags: java, c++

I am very new to C++ and Java. I succeeded in writing a simple calculator in Java, but my C++-translation crashes with an [Access violation on writing to 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/incra.png).

I know that indicates a problem with a `NULL`-pointer, but I do not see where. Also it sometimes runs but sometimes crashes so I have no idea how to trace and debug it.

#### C++

```
int main() {
    bool success = false;
    double total = 0.0;
    string line = "text";
    int in = 1;
    do{
        cout << "\nPlease enter simple equation\n";
        double operands[2];
        getline(cin, line);
        char input [10];
        strcpy_s(input, line.c_str());
        int j = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while(i < sizeof(operands)){
            string str = "";
            if(input[j] <= 57 && input[j] >= 48 || input[j] == 46){
                while(input[j] <= 57 && input[j] >= 48 || input[j] == 46){
                    str += (input[j]);
                    if(j+1 < sizeof(input))
                        j++;
                    else
                        break;
                }
                operands[i] = stod(str);
                i++;
            }else
                j++;
        }
        for (int o = 0; o < sizeof(input); o++){
            switch (input[o]){
            case 43:
                total = operands[0] + operands[1];
                break;
            case 45:
                total = operands[0] - operands[1];
                break;
            case 42:
                total = operands[0] * operands[1];
                break;
            case 47:
                total = operands[0] / operands[1];
            }
        }
        if(total){
            cout << total;
        }else{
            cout <<"Your input is incorrect! Please enter a valid equation";
            cout<< "Ex. 1 + 1";
        }
    }while(!success);
}
```

#### Java

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean success = false;
    Double total = null;
    while (!success) {
        System.out.println("\nPlease enter simple equation: ");
        try {
            double[] operands = new double[2];
            String line = in.nextLine();
            char[] input = line.toCharArray();
            StringBuilder str;
            int j = 0;
            int i = 0;
            while (i < operands.length) {
                str = new StringBuilder();
                if (input[j] <= 57 && input[j] >= 48 || input[j] == 46) {
                    while (input[j] <= 57 && input[j] >= 48 || input[j] == 46) {
                        str.append(String.valueOf(input[j]));
                        if (j + 1 < input.length) {
                            j++;
                        } else
                            break;
                    }
                    operands[i] = Double.parseDouble(str.toString());
                    i++;
                } else
                    j++;
            }
            for (int o = 0; o < input.length; o++) {
                switch (input[o]) {
                case 43:
                    total = operands[0] + operands[1];
                    break;
                case 45:
                    total = operands[0] - operands[1];
                    break;
                case 42:
                    total = operands[0] * operands[1];
                    break;
                case 47:
                    total = operands[0] / operands[1];
                }
            }
            if (total != null) {
                System.out.println(line + " = " + total);
            }else{
                System.out.println("Your input is incorrect! Please enter a valid equation");
                System.out.println("Ex. 1 + 1");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Your input is incorrect! Please enter a valid equation");
            System.out.println("Ex. 1 + 1");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try using a C++ debugger.

Comment: Yes, click the Break button to see which line of code is at fault.

Comment: There's no point in reading your string and then copying it straight over to a C string. There's also no point in using arrays that don't know their own size, evidently, because you're iterating through it wrong.

Comment: @StilesCrisis it opens the iosfwd file and tells me that the error is there. that's kinda weird

Comment: could you make it compilable?

Comment: You know that a `double` is probably 8 big?

Comment: @chris not sure what you mean about the string, but the array is i do not know its size it depends on the how many characters there are

Comment: @Deduplicator what do you mean (this is my first code in c++ so i don't really inderstand how it operates) | does it matter what size it is? there could be decimals so i kinda need it

Comment: I mean that the `sizeof` operator (*not* a function) returns the size of its argument in bytes (`char`), not in whatever unit you want this time (like e.g. `double` for an array of `double`s).

Comment: @Jenny, You have a `std::string` with the input. Then you cripple yourself by going from there to a C string with `strcpy_s`. Just use the `std::string`. Then you loop probably 16 times over an array with two elements. Use `std::array` and voila, you have `arr.size()`.

Comment: @chris you suggest i read the string into the array?? not sure i understand.

Comment: Just get rid of the `strcpy_s` call and use `line` instead of `input`. It works the same way.

Comment: Unrelated to your real problem, I strongly recommend use `'0'` instead of `48`, etc (in fact, use `isdigit()` or `Character.isDigit()`) to make your code much more understandable.

Comment: @Jenny `i have no idea how to trace and debug it.`  You're using Visual C++.  It has one of the best debuggers ever developed for a C++ environment.  There shouldn't be an excuse for not using it.

Comment: @Jenny - Also C++ is not Java.  You're making the mistake of attempting to take a Java program and make a line-by-line translation to C++.  Just because C++ looks something like Java, it doesn't make it suitable to attempt these types of translations.  Instead, learn C++ proper and apply C++ constructs to write the program.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I totally agree with you but if you are learning a new language, rote translation is an early step on that road. It's totally natural; everyone has to start somewhere. Actually writing native-looking C++ will come with time.

Comment: @StilesCrisis, I personally hope there's a XX for C++ Programmers book. If not, any good book on the language still does nicely for at least skimming through.

Comment: I notice that you only provide two parameters to the strcpy_s function, not three. Could this be the cause? When using the templated version you need to specify strcpy_s(input[10], line.c_str()). Running the program in a debugger will put you right on the failure line would be a valuable tool. P.S. This is a different 'chris'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the sizeof keyword gives the size of a variable (or type) in bytes. This is causing your loop to run too many times, leading to a buffer overflow.
If you change the statement to

```
while (i < sizeof(operands) / sizeof (operands[0]) ){
```

that will make it loop only twice. (note you don't need to put the parameters to sizeof in brackets, unless it is a type).

The next step should be to see how to make the program simpler by using more c++ like code (for example, no need to copy to a char array as you can access the std::string's characters using the array access operator).

Note: You should also read the comments, as there are a lot of good suggestions there.